# How To Delete a Private Channel

Tags: slack

I created a slack work space for my team. I just recently managed the channel permissions. I found out that my team members created a private channel that I can't see. How can I delete it without them knowing?

Comment: Please don't abuse tags like that.

Answer (score 3):

You can not delete a private channel that you are not a member of and therefore can not see. And it does not matter what role you have. Its the same for admins and owners.

If you are the owner of this Slack and want to avoid this kind of situation in the future I would recommend to restrict who can create private channels to trusted people only (e.g. owners only).